# Updating Web Feature Layer Pop-ups

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, arcgis-online-webmap

I have a web feature layer that I use across multiple Web Maps edited in ArcGIS Pro. When I edit layer features in one map and save the Web Map, that will update the features across all the maps. But when I edit the pop-ups for a feature, I can't seem to find a way to update the feature pop ups in the WFL, so every time I add one of the layers to a map I have to make the same edits to the pop up. Is there any way to edit the WFL so that the pop up edits will stick?

I've tried:

- Save Web Map (updates features but not pop up definitions)
- Publish/Overwrite Web Layer (fails with error 00102: Map does not contain a required layer type for Web Feature Layer)
- Replace Web Layer (only shows basemap layer)